# What is Wookiee fur really made of?

Tags: star-wars, costume

**Out of universe, what is Wookiee fur made of?**

[image: Wookiees]

This fearsome-looking bunch are all actors in costume, presumably. So what material was used to make those costumes?

Comment: Carpet.‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪.‪.

Comment: In-universe, it's made of wookiee-fur.

Comment: Trump cast-offs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**According to the traveling Smithsonian Exhibit, Chewbacca's costume was made of yak hair and mohair.** Presumably, the other wookiee suits were as well. The exhibit features screen-used costumes and props from all six movies, including one of the original Chewbacca costumes.

[This article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/ap/article-2935987/Obi-Wan-Chewbacca-Vader-gang-reunite-new-exhibit.html) about the exhibit mentions the costume's materials specifically.

> Among the other display descriptions: Amidala's wedding dress was made partly out of an Italian lace bedspread; and **Chewbacca's fur is a combination of Yak hair and mohair.**

The [Smithsonian's page for the exhibition](http://www.sites.si.edu/starwarsandthepowerofcostume/) also mentions it:

> **Yak hair and mohair** costume of the towering Wookiee Chewbacca

The [Smithsonian's page for the costume itself](http://www.powerofcostume.si.edu/chewbacca.html) also mentions it:

> Designed by concept artist Ralph McQuarrie and produced by Stuart Freeborn, **the expressive costume is made from yak hair and mohair.**

National Fiber Technology, the company who [supplied the hair/fabric for the wookiee costumes in the prequels](https://web.archive.org/web/20051230235805/http://www.ecnnews.com/cgi-bin/05/etarchivestory.pl?200505+fn-BU_001.htm-20050508) stated that  70-80 square feet of hair was used to make each costume. (note and forgive the horrible misspelling of the word "wookiee" throughout the linked article).

Comment: Thanks, nice answer! But what is the mohair made of - goat or rabbit hair?

Comment: The mohair is made from mos, obviously.

Comment: Mohair is always hair from an angora goat. Angora wool from an angora rabbit is different and separate.

Comment: OK, gotcha. Was this costume used for all the films Chewbacca appears in?

Comment: Yes, the one in the touring exhibit was one of the OT screen-used costumes. It was labeled as being made of yak hair and mohair.